# Finding out which page layouts are available for an object with APEX

Tags: apex, metadata, tooling-api, page-layout

When you check the `Metadata.Operations.retrieve` method, It requires you to know prior the `fullname` for the page layout you want to retrieve, and the `Layout` object it's not available with regular *SOQL*, is there a way to findout all layouts available with *APEX* and not using the tooling REST API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_layout.htm) is your friend here.

You can make a call to `/services/data/v33.0/tooling/query/` and query the layouts per object. For example:

`/services/data/v33.0/tooling/query/?q=Select+id,name,createdDate,fullName+from+Layout+where+EntityDefinitionId=XXX`

There may be other ways that are simpler, but this is the one that comes to mind.

PS: If you're in Classic, you can use your SessionId to authenticate. In Lightning, you may need to get creative.

Comment: Named credentials in Lightning.

Comment: Indeed @PranayJaiswal, great call

Comment: Is this the only way? I mean, doing _external_ api calls, with APEX to salesforce, doesn't sound like a best practice, that is why I'm trying to avoid it.

Comment: If this is the only way to get that data. I don't think the question of best practice comes to picture.  Best practices are when you have alternatives, Salesforce has not released any API for page layouts yet, hopefully, in future it does.

Comment: @ekiim, I agree 100% with Pranay. It's the best practice because it is the only practice.

Comment: @ekiim This is a bit of a limitation of the current implementation. Salesforce has said they'd make more operations available in the future, so we can just hope that getting a list of page layouts is one of them.

Comment: I see, well, I guess we can pin this question, @SebastianKessel edits and expand why It's currently not possible, (with some info on this comments), I think, this could be a common question. I suppose.

Comment: Session ID works in Visualforce controllers in Lightning Experience. Just not in a Lightning Component Apex controller.